# What is the behavior of an unsigned int converted to an unsigned char in the C99 standard?

Tags: c, casting, c99, endianness, type-conversion

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    unsigned int x = 64;
    x += 1023;

    unsigned char y = x;

    printf("%u\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

The variable `y` holds the value `63` on my machine. Does the C99 standard guarantee that the least significant byte will be stored when an **unsigned int** is converted to an **unsigned char**, or does the endianness of the machine affect the convertion?

Comment: It should print 63, not 65.

Comment: A quibble: There is no cast in your program. A cast is an operator that performs an explicit conversion; it consists of a parenthesized type name. You have an implicit conversion (which behaves the same way an explicit cast `unsigned char y = (unsigned char)x;` would).

Comment: @wildplasser Oops I misread the output of my program.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks for the semantic correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard says this about converting to an unsigned type:

> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type
>   other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it
>   is unchanged.
>
> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by
>   repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
>   can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
>   the new type.

Which is a fancy way of saying the value wraps around if it doesn't fit. So in your case **you'll always get 63**, on all machines, unless your `unsigned char` can actually store more than 255: it has nothing to do with endianness.

Comment: @R.. True, I added that bit.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, would the wrapped value be equivalent to the least significant byte?

Comment: Modulo by 256 (or the respective max value of unsigned char + 1) appears to truncate the higher bytes, so I suspect only the least significant byte is evaluated in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Endianness does not matter for the cast. Only the C value matters.